# How long would it take a city to starve?

Tags: food, dystopia, cities

In the dystopian story that I’m writing with my dad, there are two races of people: humans and mutants.

The dictator of the only surviving state finds out that his son turned into a mutant and accidentally killed his mother (the governor’s wife). The governor sends part of his state (which is built on the back of a huge bird) into the sky to starve his son to death (and everyone else, but mainly his son).

The state has an area of about 4,811 square miles. My question is: how long would it take for them to run out of food? (assuming they have no way to make more food once they’re up there, and that they would cannibalize each other.) And if it takes more that 30 years, would there be any quicker methods of killing them?

Comment: This will be an interesting question, but there is insufficient data to make more than a wild guess. What population. What level of stores. With so much floorspace, why is no agriculture assumed? Is climate affected? Are watersources affected? Tech level? Will they have power, refrigeration, replicators? Do they just panic or is there a Plan?

Comment: 4811 square miles is almost the size of Connecticut. That's a big bird.

Answer (score 5):

According to the various estimates rattling around you've given enough land to comfortably feed between 1.5 - 6 million people, though some would suggest even more could be fed with higher density methods and vertical farms.

Assuming they still have a water supply and sufficient technology/magic up there, they're never going to starve.

If you want to kill them quickly just send this bird up to high altitude for a while and kill them with hypoxia.

Answer (score 3):

Starvation kills within months, the actual time depending on details you don't provide, like how much food there is stored when the isolation happens, what is the consumption rate (do they start rationing right away or do they take some time to realize they are cut off from the rest of the world?).

But before starvation has time to kill, thirst will do if no source of drink water is available. Lack of water kills within few days.

Answer (score 2):

#### Could be hundreds of years.

So the state that's up in the air is 12460.43 sqkm - approximately 111km * 111km. You haven't specified population or density, so lets go for the best case scenario:

Lets assume the land is crammed full of people at modern population densities and there's a heavily fortified and armed upper class and a weak unarmed lower class that can't fight back.

Lets not worry about them trying to grow food, or going through their cupboards, or eating random plants or eating the couch or whatever. Lets just jump straight to cannibalism as it's what your asking about.

If the population is really dense - 12460.43 sqkm is 15 NYC's, or multiplying that out, 126 million people. Canabalising all of them is enough to feed 1 person for 10 million years, or, more realistically, feed 100,000 people for 100 years. Especially if the altitude is cold and there's natural preservation of the meat. (Otherwise you'll waste a huge % of your food by feeding it to someone whose going to become food later, and you may only last a few years).

Some lottery system or capital punishment could stretch that even further.

Water could be an issue, but your massive patch of land is unlikely to be lakeless. Rain will fall and can be captured.

Biggest issue may be prion diseases, but that'll take a few decades to be a concern, and when widespread cannibalisms is happening Creutzfeldt-Jakob disease has a way of seeming insignificant.

But yes there is a quicker way. Have the bird fly to 9km high and watch everyone pass out and asphyxiate. Most'll be dead within the hour. Give it a week for the stragglers and mountaineers.

Answer (score 2):

**Riots kill before hunger.**

These are humans and mutants just like us, right? Then I can assure you that even before starvation or thirst kills them they will kill each other.

The best thing is, as soon as the general public (humans and mutants alike) finds out that they are being punished for the deeds of a single boy, they will make sure that this one dies first. After that, if the order is not presumed they will simply kill each other, cannibalize, and the rest will commit suicide out of depression. Should not take more than 5 years, or a decade at max.

If they somehow presume order and governance, they will try to contact the surface world to tell the governor that the real culprit is dead and let them come back.

Answer (score 2):

**528 days**

*So basically you have a differential equation question about cannibalism :D, I couldn't be happier, finally math is useful!!*

So assuming you have no food (or you eat it all before cannibalism starts) you have a whole population that you can express in calories. Assuming the people are smart about it, you invent a lottery system (or any other system) where one person gets eaten equally shared among all occupants. After the person is fully eaten you go on with the next, while you have one person less to feed. In this way you can stretch your food supplies the longest while still living relatively comfortable, I guess?

So how long does it take until you reach the last person.

**The Assumptions**

- 1 person = 60 kg (of usable meat)
- 60 kg of meat = 85800 kcal.
- 1 person needs = 2250 kcal (average of men and women)

So than it become a simple first order differential equation in the form:

> ```
> dy/dt =ky
> ```

Here y is the number of calories in the entire city at a given time, k is the rate at which the calories are eaten as ratio and y' is the change in the rate at which the calories are eaten. Luckily this equation is a solvable and becomes,

> y(t) = C exp(kt)

Here C is the starting population (in calories). So if you now plug this into a graphing program.

- C = 1000000*85800 (1M people * 85800 kcal per person)
- k = 2250/85800 (The rate at which the calories would shrink per day)

So if we graph it we get an exponential decay.
[image: The calorie decrease of the city]
To hopefully make it more readable near the end day, with a logarithmic y-axis.
[image: The calorie decrease of the city logarithmic]

So around day 528 only 85000 kcal are left in the city, meaning only one human is left, presumably the son. This of course starting with a million people.

Comment: Cool answer, using math in strange places is fun. In case you are unaware of it, you can insert mathematical expressions using [TeX style expressions enclosed in $ signs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) which can allow you to use more complicated expressions if needed